# Clip/Cut everything outside of Polygon or fill the outside with white

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, clip

I have a square of colored noise with an triangle on it.
Now, I want the polygon to cut this noise like a "cookie cutter" on christmas. Resulting in an triangle of noise that is surrounded by a polygon path.

How can i clip all pixels that overlap the Polygon border and then save it as pdf?

I came up with 2 ideas:

- **Method 1** use a function that tests whether the pixel (colored noise) falls in the shape or not. Lets do it!
  **Problem**: The edges of the border pixels go out of the line. In this example its quite minimal. You could argue just making the polygon-line a little bit bigger.
- **Method 2** Inverse the Polygon Shape (equal to: fill outside of polygon) and then fill it with white.
  **Problem**:
  In the plot preview window the result looks like i want it. When i save it as PDF i get an result of everything is white with the black polygon shapes.

**Reproducible example**:

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(SDMTools)
polyGony <- c(0,0,100,50,50,100) %>% matrix(ncol=2,byrow = T) %>% as.data.frame()
deltaN <- 200  #grid width
sp1<-seq(1,100,length=deltaN)
sp2<-seq(1,100,length=deltaN)
sp<-expand.grid(x=sp1,y=sp2)

set.seed(1337)
sp$z <- sample(1:30,nrow(sp),replace = T)

# Method 1
outin = SDMTools::pnt.in.poly(sp[,1:2],polyGony)
outin$z <- sp$z
pointsInsideTri <- outin[outin$pip==1,-3]

p <- ggplot(pointsInsideTri, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#FFCd94", "#FF69B4", "#FF0000","#4C0000","#000000"))

p + geom_polygon(data = polyGony, aes(V1,V2),color="black", fill=NA) + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)

# Method 2
outSQ <-c(0,0,100,0,100,100,0,100)
invPolyGony <- c(outSQ,0,0,100,50,50,100) %>% matrix(ncol=2,byrow = T) %>% as.data.frame()


    p <- ggplot(sp, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#FFCd94", "#FF69B4", "#FF0000","#4C0000","#000000"))

    p + geom_polygon(data = invPolyGony, aes(V1,V2) ,colour="black", fill="white") + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

Comment: Is the pdf your only problem? To me it is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: i want to surround a pixel based image with an polygon path. No pixels should "lap" out of the polygon borders. Then i want to save it in a pdf file.

Comment: What I understand, your story is misleading (or wrong). You know what you want to do and which methods you want to use. Your problem is only how to save the result as pdf.

Comment: Dear Christoph, i tried to condence my question in the end again! Yes, i know what i want. Yet i dont know how to do it, Method1 and 2 are my best tries. Its not compulsary to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i now know what the problem was. In order to fill everything outside of a polygon, the path (the hole in the middle) needs to "run" clockwise, the outter border needs to run counter-clockwise.

I made a simple example. We have a polygon of a star. I want everything outside of the star to be red.

```
star <- c(25.000,1.000,31.000,18.000,49.000,18.000,35.000,29.000,40.000,46.000,
          25.000,36.000,10.000,46.000,15.000,29.000,1.000,18.000,19.000,18.000) %>% matrix(ncol=2, byrow=T)
star <- rbind(star,star[1,])
rim  <- c(0,0, 50,0, 50,50,0,50,0,0) %>% matrix(ncol=2, byrow=T)

datapolyM <- rbind(rim,star) %>% as.data.frame()
names(datapolyM) <- c("x","y")

ggplot(datapolyM, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill="red", colour="black")
```

## Export to pdf! You will see that the whole image is filled red!

Now lets turn the path of the star to run clockwise: Please respect the apply and reverse command in the second line:

```
star <- c(25.000,1.000,31.000,18.000,49.000,18.000,35.000,29.000,40.000,46.000,
          25.000,36.000,10.000,46.000,15.000,29.000,1.000,18.000,19.000,18.000) %>% matrix(ncol=2, byrow=T) %>% apply(2, rev)
star <- rbind(star,star[1,])
rim  <- c(0,0, 50,0, 50,50,0,50,0,0) %>% matrix(ncol=2, byrow=T)

datapolyM <- rbind(rim,star) %>% as.data.frame()
names(datapolyM) <- c("x","y")
datapolyM$id <- "a"

ggplot(datapolyM, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_polygon(fill="red")
```

## Now export to pdf again. You will see it worked this time! You have filled everything outside of a given polygon-shape!

Comment: Great solution! It applies naturally to mapping when you want to highlight tiles with conflicting jurisdictions, such as census tracts and congressional districts.

Comment: Nice, I adapted this slightly for my use, to restrict a raster to a convex hull but it worked really well! Running 'clockwise' is key to solving this.